# How to set an EntityType field to be readonly/disabled, so that value cannot be edited but is still sent with the form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

In Symfony 6, when I render en `EntityType` (HTML select field) setting `readonly` attribute, this field can actually be modified (since `readonly` does not work for `<select>` elements)..

If I set `disabled`, then, I get an error as this field is required.

How can I avoid this field to be modified but rendered?

```
class ClientFileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('clientFileType', EntityType::class, ['label' => 'Tipo',
                                                        'required' => true,
                                                        'class' => TypeOfClientFile::class,
                                                        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                                                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('T')
                                                                ->orderBy('T.name', 'ASC');
                                                        }])
    // (...)
}
```

This is twig template code, field is `readonly` only when modifying, but editable on new entity:

```
{{ form_row(form.clientFileType, {'attr': {'readonly': (client_file.id != null) }}) }}
```

Comment: What kind of behavior are you expecting with a required field that is disabled ?

Comment: It should be readonly only when the entity has an id, this is, you can set this value when creating a new entity, but not modify it later.

Comment: The readonly attr is only added if `entity.id != null`

Comment: I don't need `disabled` what I need is the field blocked for edition. Those "related" questions are not really related, as `readonly` works properly for text fields, but not for select field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `disabled` and `required` at the same time. If you think about it, you'll realize it doesn't make sense: with `required` you are telling "this value needs to be filled in and sent", with `disabled` you are saying "ignore and do not send the value for this field".

For this, you'll have to implement a slightly more sophisticated logic.

If the value field is to be disabled, then maybe you no longer need to display it as a `select`. You do not need the options (the user can't choose a new one), so why query them and render them?

In this case, simply add a different field type for different situations: If the field is to be `disabled`, show a different UI element, and send the appropriate data.

A crude example (you'll have to polish it so it suits your use-case, haven't actually ran it in my project, but the idea works):

```php
class ClientFileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        if ($options['client_file']) {
            $builder->add('clientFileType', HiddenType::class, [
                 'value' => $options['client_file'],
            ]);

            $builder->add('clientFileTypeDisplay', TextType::class, [
              'label' => 'Tipo',
              'value' => $options['client_file_name'],
              'disabled' => true,
            ]);
        } else {
            $builder
                ->add('clientFileType', EntityType::class, ['label' => 'Tipo',
                    'required' => true,
                    'class' => TypeOfClientFile::class,
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('T')
                            ->orderBy('T.name', 'ASC');
                    }]);
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'client_file' => 'int',
            'client_file_name' => '',
        ]);

        $resolver->addAllowedTypes('client_file', 'integer');
        $resolver->addAllowedTypes('client_file_name', 'string');
    }
}
```

Then when creating your form in your controller, you'll set the options if necessary:

```php
$form = $this->createForm(ClientFileType::class, options: [
   'client_file' => $client_file_id, // or 0 if not applicable,
    'client_flie_name' => $client_file_name // the actual name, so you don't have to make a query in the form
]);
```

And when rendering it:

```
{{ form_row(form.clientFileType) }}

{% if client_file.id %}
{{ form_row(form.clientFileTypeDisplay) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, when rendering clientFileType as `hidden` I get this error on POST (`$form->handleRequest($request)`):

*Expected argument of type "?App\Entity\ClientFileType", "string" given at property path "clientFileType"*

Comment: You may need to adjust the code a bit, depending on your use case. I use a similar approach on some of my forms fine. How are you creating your form? You need to pass different options depending when you are creating the form, adjust your controller's logic for that.

Comment: It's ok, I'll keep it as correct answer, just wrote comment for other people who could see it. What I actually did is render select as display none (maybe not the nicest solution), and use the field `clientFileTypeDisplay` as you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use for that field.  So you're able to configure it based on a New value vs Populated value.  You can read more about it here.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html

```
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, [ $this, 'onPreSetData' ]);
}

public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event): void
{
  ...
}
```